# Int of Int in Ocaml types

Tags: types, ocaml, variant, algebraic-data-types

In an assignment, I have two user-defined types. Type a uses `INT of int` and type b uses `Int of int`. As far as I understand, this means that both these types can accept an `int` as part of that type. Is there any way to convert between types a and b? I've tried typecasting like

```
let typeA = INT 5
let typeB = Int 5
let cast = INT(typeB)
```

but that throws a type mismatch error.

Comment: You need to explicitly write a function that will "extract" the value from an `Int` and create a new `INT` with that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml is a strongly typed language, so there is no way in general to "type cast" from one type to another.

You can write a function that converts one type to another, however. For example, there is a built-in function named `float_of_int` that converts a float to an int. There is also `int_of_float` (which throws away any fractional part of the float value).

You can easily write functions in a similar spirit to convert between your two types.

Here's some code that contains all the ideas you need (I think):

```
type mytype = MyConstructor of int

let increment (MyConstructor x) = MyConstructor (x + 1)
```